# Inserting Excel data into SQLite column

Tags: sql, excel, sqlite

I have a problem: I have a MS excel `(.xlsx)` file with thousands of entries. I need to insert the data from excel file into a SQLite column. I have seen from the existing answers that it can be achieved from `INSERT INTO` statement as shown below:

```
INSERT INTO artists (name)
VALUES
    ("Buddy Rich"),
    ("Candido"),
    ("Charlie Byrd");
```

But the problem is we have to add/insert the entries manually which is not possible in case if we have 10,000 entries in excel file.

In a nutshell, I am trying to achieve three things here:

1. Create new column in existing SQLite database
2. Add or insert data of excel file into that new column of SQLite.
3. The excel data has more than 10,000 entries in a single column. How can I insert the big data of excel into the new column of SQLite database?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're mixing two things

- creating columns on the table (`alter table ... add column ...`)
- inserting data into already existing column

Additionally you should specify if you want to insert these new data or rather update some existing rows using these data.

For SQLite it seems that the easiest way would be to save this `.xlsx` file as a `csv` (directly in Excel) and then import that using `.import` sqlite cli command (see [that](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files:%7E:text=Use%20the%20%22.import%22%20command%20to%20import,CSV%20data%20is%20to%20be%20inserted.)).

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope it will make the things more clear.

Comment: Ok, thanks.So another question - do you want to add this new column to some already existing table (if so, does it have already any data/rows) or this could be totally new table with this column only? Next step would be to add some id or index on that new column most likely, but it depends on use case of this new data.